# Adding 4 variables into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have 4 variables that show coordinates x and y/

e.g:

```
first_co = [0,0]
second_co = [100,200]
third_co = [300,400]
fourth_co = [800,1000]
```

When i tried to just declare a numpy array as

```
box = np.array([first_co],[second_co],[third_co],[fourth_co])
```

I got a value error, how do I declare a numpy array with 4 variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to feed a (nested) list of lists to `np.array`:

```
box = np.array([first_co, second_co, third_co, fourth_co])

box.dtype  # dtype('int32')
```

Result:

```
array([[   0,    0],
       [ 100,  200],
       [ 300,  400],
       [ 800, 1000]])
```

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) make this clear:

> **object : *array_like***
>
> An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
>   `__array__` method returns an array, or **any (nested) sequence**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
box = np.array([first_co,second_co,third_co,fourth_co])
```