# how to put symbol variable to numpy function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

it seems that this question has been sorted out many times, but personally I found nothing about how to put a symbol variable in the numpy function

My MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ksi_list = []
for m in np.arange(1,8):
    ksi = np.sqrt((2*3.14*500/1400)**2-(np.pi*m/10)**2)
    ksi_list.append(ksi)


z = symbols('z')

psi_m_list = []
for s in np.arange(len(ksi_list)):
    psi_m = np.cos(z*np.sqrt(k**2-np.square(ksi_list[s])))
    psi_z_list.append(psi_m)
psi_m_list
```

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable cos method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding 4 variables into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186022/adding-4-variables-into-numpy-array)

Comment: You can't do that.  `Z=np.array(z)` is an object dtype array.  Math on that kind of array is limited.  `Z*Z` works.  `np.cos(Z)` does not.  But why are you trying to do this?

Comment: try to put it in list

Comment: what to make a list of functions

Comment: `sympy` has its own `cos` and `sqrt`.  Again, why numpy?  As a general rule `sympy` and `numpy` don't work well together, or at least not easily.  You really have to understand both to do something useful that way.

Comment: thanks for reply. but how can I plot sum(psi_m_list)?  Because python says that it is TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float when plt.plot(sum(psi_m_list))